# Why doesn't JS integer increment when PHP row limit is not exceeded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an inView function that parses an input's value (`input type="hidden" id="pageno" value=""`) and adds 1 to it [when an image is in view].

**InfiniteScroll.js**

```
 //#Loader is the ID  of the image
 $('#Loader').on('inview', function(event, isInView) {

        if (isInView) {

        //Pagination    
        var nextPage = parseInt($('#pageno').val()) + 1;

            ...
```

Then I have a totally separate function (`filter_data()`) that's also an AJAX call, that fetches data from the users PHP input. When this function runs, I want `id="pageno" value="0"` (I need the pagination to start from scratch so the user can see all the PHP rows generated [based on their input]). So I changed the `nextPage` variable to 0 when the AJAX call's data function is updated (0+1=1).

**Filters.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

    //Pagination
    var nextPage = 0; //InfiniteScroll.js will add 1 to this

    filter_data();

    function filter_data() {

        ...
```

My problem is that when there aren't enough rows (in PHP), `id="pageno"` doesn't increment by 1 when `#Loader` is in view. But when I add `console.log(data)` to the `success` function to **Filters.js**'s AJAX call I see there are iterations of PHP rows generated in the data function (again, this is based on the users input).

**Filters.js**

```
...

success:

    function(data) {

        console.log(data);

        ...
```

Why doesn't the **Filters.js**'s `nextPage` variable value increment as expected when there is less then one page of iterations (every page has a limit of 10 iterations)?

Comment: There is no PHP here. Please remove the PHP tag.

Comment: Fixed - I thought it would be good for context. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Your `nextPage` variables in your two totally separate functions are totally separate variables.  Incrementing one doesn't increment the other.

Comment: I thought so also [when I first started this project] but after attempting it; if there are more then 10 iterations (10 is limit per page in PHP) then the `id="pageno"` **does** increment by + 1 (as expected)

Comment: @ArielZabihi You haven't provided enough code for me to evaluate that statement.  I can tell you that the two variables are **definitely** separate, but I can't tell for sure whether it matters.

Comment: Is there a way for me to dump my code here? (I'm new)

Comment: @ArielZabihi Ideally, you should make a reduced copy of your code that has the same problem with as little code as possible (a "Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example").  I wouldn't want to look through a large codebase for the problem, even if you find a way to provide it to me.

Comment: Hey, so I had a good nights rest woke up and thought of a fix. Sorry to waste your time. Thanks for the help!